# Call IronPython from standard Python

Tags: python, .net, interop, ironpython, python.net

How can I call an IronPython function from within Python? Is there an easy way to interface the two. I need the flexibility of both a full set of proper Python libraries that are not available in IronPython  and the latest CLR which Python .net does not currently have.

What I've tried so far is to compile a IronPython dll but I can't get it to be loaded properly within Python.

My attempt to make IronPython n callable from Python

**foo.py**

```
def foo():
    print 'hello world'
```

**compile_ipy.py**

```
import clr
clr.CompileModules("foo.dll", "foo.py")
```

My attempt's to call Iron Python From Python

**call_ipy_from_py1.py**

```
import ctypes
dll = ctypes.WindDLL('foo.dll')
dll.foo() # AttributeError: function 'foo' not found
```

**call_ipy_from_py2.py**

```
import ctypes
dll = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('foo.dll')
dll.foo() # AttributeError: function 'foo' not found
```

Comment: Can you give a simple example?

Comment: @PeterWood Let's start with calling a function that print's hello world in IronPython from Python, I'll include whati've tried as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET DLLs are not the same as C DLLs (which you can use via `ctypes`). You can, however, use the Python.NET library to call the function like this:

```
import clr # Imports Python.Runtime.dll
import foo # Imports foo.dll
foo.foo()
```

I don't know what you mean by "latest CLR which Python .net does not currently have". You can use the version provided here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pythonnet if you need to use CPython 3, I'm using it with .NET 4.5.1 libraries without issues.

Comment: I didn't know about these binaries but I get the following error when I `import clr` installed this way
`ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.`

Comment: Also the on the pythonnet source page they list clr 4.0 as the latest, http://sourceforge.net/projects/pythonnet/files/

Comment: Regarding the first comment: That normally means that it can't find the DLLs or that you installed the wrong ones (i.e. 64 bit on a 32 bit system). Are `Python.Runtime.dll` and `clr.pyd` in your `site-packages` directory?

Comment: Regarding the second one: That page is severly outdated, since the project was kind-of abandoned. Development continued for a while here: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet and here (for Python 3): https://github.com/renshawbay/pythonnet

Comment: yes both `Python.Runtime.dll` and `clr.pyd` are in my `site-packages` directory. To your second point the outdated packages are part of my reasoning behind wanting to call `IronPython` from Python

Comment: Ah I got this to work correctly now, it was conflicting with another clr.pyd in my Python root directory